# After K8s Master reboot, apiserver throws error “x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid”

Tags: kubernetes, kubespray

I have multimaster kubernetes cluster setup using Kubespray.
I ran an application using helm on it which increased the load on master drastically. this made master almost inaccessible. After that I shutdown masters one by one and increased RAM and CPU on them. But after rebooting, both apiserver and scheduler pods are failing to start. They are in "CreateContainerError" state.

APIserver is logging lot of errors with the message `x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid`.

There are other threads for this error and most of them suggest to fix apiserver or cluster certificates. But this is newly setup cluster and certificates are valid till 2020.

Here are some details of my cluster.

```
CentOS Linux release: 7.6.1810 (Core)
Docker version: 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
```

Kubernetes Version

```
Client Version: v1.13.2
Server Version: v1.13.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very much possible that during shutdown/reboot, docker containers for apiserver and scheduler got exited with non zero exit status like **255**. I sugggest you to first remove all containers with non zero exit status using docker rm command. Do this on all masters, rather on worker nodes as well.

By default, kubernetes starts new pods for all services (apiserver, shceduler, controller-manager, dns, pod network etc.) after a reboot. You can see newly started containers for these services using docker commands
 example:

```
docker ps -a | grep "kube-apiserver" OR
docker ps -a | grep "kube-scheduler"
```

after removing exited containers, I believe, new pods for apiserver and scheduler should run properly in the cluster and should be in "Running" status.